# Mac update 10.13.4 - how do I exit the installer?

Tags: macos, software-update

Like many people my attempt to install update 10.13.4 has not worked. A 2012 Mac Air running OS 10.13.3 with the usual "resource not found" and exit the installer. I click restart and stuck in the loop.

I can hold <kbd>Option</kbd> at boot and choose the installer or the normal drive, so yes, I can get boot fine.  I do not want to install the update now. I will wait until a better update is released later.

So, how do I stop the installer so I do not have to hold <kbd>Option</kbd>at boot?

Added: I have not lost anything and can use the computer fine. I just want to stop the computer defaulting to the installer instead of the normal drive.

When I alt/option at boot I have 2 drive choices on the DOS like screen - the installer or the original drive.

Comment: Do you have a backup in case you want to just erase and install?

Comment: Also, what exactly is shown on your Mac screen when you allow it to start up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple stores the boot volume in NVRAM with some other settings, have you tried resetting that and then when you boot to the normal os, go to startup options and choose the Mac OS to be th default os to boot?

That’s the normal way to reset a sticky choice you don’t prefer when there are several OS to boot or choose.

Comment: I'll look into it.